# Shortcuts to comment and uncomment SQL queries in SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)

Tags: sql, ssms, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, sql-comments

To comment 3 SQL queries with shortcuts in SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) as shown below, first, I dragged them, then pressed only one of **CTRL+K** or **CTRL+C** but I couldn't comment them.

[image]

And, to uncomment 3 SQL queries with shortcuts in SSMS as shown below, first, I dragged them, then pressed only one of **CTRL+K** or **CTRL+U** but I couldn't uncomment them.

[image]

Actually, [**the documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) explains the shortcuts to comment and uncomment as shown below but I couldn't comment and uncomment them:

> Make the selected text a comment    CTRL+K, CTRL+C
> Uncomment the selected text            CTRL+K, CTRL+U

So, is it impossible to comment and uncomment 3 SQL queries with the shortcuts above in SSMS?

Answer (score 3):

No, in SSMS, it's possible to comment and uncomment 3 SQL queries with the shortcuts which [**the documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) explains.

To comment 3 SQL queries with the shortcuts in SSMS, after dragging them, you first need to press **CTRL+K**, then next need to press **CTRL+C** continuously instead of pressing only one of **CTRL+K** or **CTRL+C**:

[image]

And, to uncomment 3 SQL queries with the shortcuts in SSMS, after dragging them, you first need to press **CTRL+K**, then next need to press **CTRL+U** continuously instead of pressing only one of **CTRL+K** or **CTRL+U**:

[image]

In addition, there is **the message "Ready" by default** at the bottom left corner of SSMS as shown below:

[image]

Then, if pressing **CTRL+K**, **the message *"(Ctrl+K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..."*** is displayed as shown below:

[image]

Then next, if pressing **CTRL+C** to comment or **CTRL+U** to uncomment, **the message "Ready"** is displayed again as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome, at best, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2024**

If you are working on *SSMS*, use the solutions provided by **[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/ssms-tricks?view=sql-server-ver16)**. ( The previous solutions didn't work for me)

**1 - Using GUI :**

**To Comment multiple lines of code:**

*Highlight  the text, and then select the Comment button on the toolbar*

[image]

**To Uncomment  multiple lines of code:**

*Highlight  the text, and then select the Uncomment button on the toolbar*

[image]

---

**2- Using shortcuts :**

**To Comment multiple lines of code:**

Highlight the portions of text then press : `CTRL + K + C` ( please do it in order )

**Uncomment  multiple lines of code:**

Highlight the portions of text then press : `CTRL + K + U` ( please do it in order )

---

**To comment a single line** just use `--` at the start position of the line

**To comment multiple lines together **without** highlighting them** simpley put `/*` at the beginning and `*/` at the end - example :

```
/*
 SELECT * 
   FROM Courses
   WHERE CourseId = 100
*/
```